# Why does YouTube volume fade when visiting certain sites?

Tags: youtube, volume, multitasking

I use split screen YouTube and Chrome on my phone, but when I visit e.g. bbc.com the video volume fades to a much lower level.

What causes this and can it be prevented?

This is a OP3t with Android 8.0 in case that matters

Answer (score 1):

Most times this is caused by an video-ad on the website. It shouldn't happen on websites without any ad.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "on websites *that does not emit sound*". Notifications also cause a brief fade in volume.